# C# Linq To Entities Formatted DateTime in IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What I am trying to achieve is get the "FormattedTimeStamp" member variable to contain dates formatted as follows: "12/09/2015 13:00"

What I am getting instead is: "12/9/2015 13:0"

Is there anyway to do this using just plain LINQ to SQL and not propagating to the server (using AsEnumerable(), etc.)?

See below for what I have now which compiles and runs but doesn't give me what I need.

Thank you.

```
IQueryable<Import_ErrorDTO> dtoErrors = from i in errors
    select new Import_ErrorDTO
  {
      Error_ID = i.Error_ID,
      ErrorDescription = i.ErrorDescription,
      FileName = i.FileName,
      ImportTimeStamp = i.ImportTimeStamp,
      FormattedImportTimeStamp = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("Month", i.ImportTimeStamp)).Trim() + "/" +
                          SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("Day", i.ImportTimeStamp)).Trim() + "/" +
                          SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("Year", i.ImportTimeStamp)).Trim() + " " +
                          SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", i.ImportTimeStamp)).Trim() + ":" +
                          SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", i.ImportTimeStamp)),
      Program = i.Program
};
```

Comment: Formatting data should be the responsibility of presentation layer. Your query should just return a `DateTime`.

Comment: @JakubLortz I understand; due to the amount of data being pulled we found that this causes performance issues when using a "ToList" or the equivalent. Any way to do this using SqlFunctions?

Comment: I do not understand your response. You are saying that returning a DateTime object from Sql gives you an error when there is too much data? What you should be doing is just return a DateTime object as (your `ImportTimeStamp` is already perfect the way it is). Whatever is going to display this timestamp can then do something like timestamp.Format("MM/dd/yyy HH:mm") but this is presentation layer. Its nothing something that should be handled in the DAL or even in the BLL, its pure presentation.

Comment: I tried what I thought would work but it looks like you are right; what I ended up doing was projecting after my orderby, skip, and take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the opinion, that it should be handled in a presentation layer. But if you really want to do it on the SQL server, you can perpend `0` to the string representing minutes and then take only 2 rightmost characters with the `Right` function.

```
 SqlFunctions.Right("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(
     (double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("mi", i.ImportTimeStamp)), 2)
```

Comment: Marking this as correct answer; I ended up projecting after an orderby, skip, and take.

Answer (score -1):

One way to work around the issue would be to create a constructor;

```
public Import_ErrorDTO(DateTime dt)
{
     FormattedDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
}
```

and then pass in the ImportTime:

```
IQueryable<Import_ErrorDTO> dtoErrors = from i in errors
    select new Import_ErrorDTO(i.ImportTimeStamp)
  {
      Error_ID = i.Error_ID,
      ErrorDescription = i.ErrorDescription,
      FileName = i.FileName,
      ImportTimeStamp = i.ImportTimeStamp,
      Program = i.Program
};
```

Comment: It wouldn't work - LINQ to SQL supports only parameterless constructors

Comment: That is only for the entity classes. Here its dealing with a DTO object which I assume is his own type.

Comment: OP clearly wanted to execute the query on the SQL server, so I suppose the errors collection is a non-materialized `IQueryable<SomeDbEntity>` (e.g. from `db.GetTable<SomeDbEntity>()`). In that case, your code is going to throw the `NotSupportedException` because a constructor with a parameter can't be converted to the store expression.